# Skyrim spouse gold for trading

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do any spouses have more than 750 gold for trading? I've been looking all over the internet and everyone seems to be talking about the 100 gold per day thing and it's really frustrating 
Alchemists have 500 gold, general stores have 750 gold, and smithing stores usually have about 1100 to 1200 gold and  I want to know if my spouse can have more than 750 gold to trade with

Answer (score 3):

You can invest in your spouse's shop to make them have more (500) gold.  Getting the master trader perk will add another 1000 gold to their inventory for a total of 1500 gold.

There are also some [shopkeepers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage) that you can marry they may have more gold than a standard 'spouse pawnshop'.

Finally there are many mods that can adjust the amount of gold shopkeepers have, for example, the [rich merchants](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/769/?) mod.

Comment: Thankyou, it's good to know some potential options exist. I'm playing xbox so I can't do mods. Any ideas in which spouses have more money cos I can't find a list anywhere

Comment: @Jeff UESP has a list of NPCs that can be married: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage  it also tells you which ones are already shop keepers.  And if you click on their name/link it'll take you to their detailed page so you can see how much gold they can have.  For example Ghorza gra-Bagol starts with a base of 1000.